Unable to access error body through Invoke-Webrequest
I am writing a Powershell client to invoke a REST API as follows:
$response = try { 
    (Invoke-WebRequest $endpoint_url `
    -Method Post `
    -Headers $endpoint_header `
    -ErrorAction Stop)
} catch [System.Net.WebException] { 
    Write-Host "A web exception was caught: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Host $_.Exception.StackTrace
    Write-Host $response.StatusCode.Value__ $response.StatusDescription
} 

Write-Host $response.StatusCode.Value__ $response.StatusDescription
Write-Host $response.RawContent
Write-Host $response.Content

The API returns a response when it sends a 500 Internal Server Error. I wish to capture the response in the script.
The statement
Write-Host $response.Content
was something that I was hoping would work. But it works only if the API returns a 200 OK. Is there some this something I would need to do to capture this?
Thanks,
Prabal

Usually when you do not get 200 OK stratus the body is empty (content).  The status is in a http header so check $response.StatusCode.
